# Silverlight + WCF. Streaming audio and video files

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

I am creating project using Silverlight + WCF. I'm new in both technology so any suggestion will be appreciate.

My goal is to stream video and audio files with WCF and simultaneously show (play) to the client.

How it can be done with these technologies?

Or any tutorial or book suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: Hi, I have the same requirement. Actually, I want to play avi and mov file in Silverlight 5. I have found a way to call the native code, but it needs the client to change the register table of windows and add signing file in the silverlight project. That could be possible but not esay for client. I agree the use WCF could be a gread idea. Have you realized what you have asked in this post? Could you give me some suggestion? Thank you very much.

Comment: If Silverlight is not a must, I suggest you to use HTML5 and ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you don't use WCF, you use WMS, IIS Media Services, or plain old file transfer to accomplish this.  If you need to use WCF for some reason you need a [`MediaStreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that hooks into your WCF service.